# Serialization/Deserialization of my custom class and save it to binary file

Tags: java, file, serialization, deserialization

I declared a custom class in my project:

```
public class LocationData {

    private Location location;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    private int heartRate;
    private int calories;
    private int ropeMoves;
    private int dumbbellMoves;
    private int pedalRotations;
    private int wheelRotations;
    private int numberOfSteps;

    public LocationData(Location location, LocalDateTime localDateTime, int heartRate, int calories, int ropeMoves, int dumbbellMoves, int pedalRotation, int wheelRotations, int numberOfSteps) {
        this.location = location;
        this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
        this.heartRate = heartRate;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.ropeMoves = ropeMoves;
        this.dumbbellMoves = dumbbellMoves;
        this.pedalRotations = pedalRotations;
        this.wheelRotations = wheelRotations;
        this.numberOfSteps = numberOfSteps;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime;
    }

    // Other getters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationData[" +
                "\n\tlocation=" + location +
                "\n\tlocalDateTime=" + localDateTime +
                "\n\tcalories=" + calories +
                "\n\theartRate=" + heartRate +
                "\n\tropeMoves=" + ropeMoves +
                "\n\tdumbbellMoves=" + dumbbellMoves +
                "\n\tpedalRotations=" + pedalRotations +
                "\n\twheelRotations=" + wheelRotations +
                "\n\tnumberOfSteps=" + numberOfSteps +
                "]";
    }
}
```

It represents a location plus some infos. Then I save a `List` of `LocationData` to create a "route".

**I need to save this List (called `location`) to a file because the user, in the future, will ask to retrieve it to create a GPX file.**

I think that the best solution is make the `LocationData` class serializable, but I don't know how to serialize (then deserialize) it. So... I need to understand how:

1. Serialize `LocationData` class
2. Deserialize `LocationData` class
3. Create a List of serialized `LocationData`
4. Write the list in a file
5. Read the list from a file

Comment: Perhaps you should follow a tutorial on serializing objects and writing them to files: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `implements Serializable` to the class definition, but you don't have to implement `Serializable`'s methods - Object already has a default implementation, and the Serializable interface is used as a declarative.

You also need to ensure that `Location` and `LocalDateTime` are both Serializable.

Finally, once that's all in place you can use ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream to read and write your objects